# Is it grammatically correct to say "Year of built"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

Is it grammatically correct to say:

> Year of built 1922

when talking about house or some other building?

I know i should probably use phrase:

> Built in 1922

or just

> Built 1922

but I wonder if that first phrase is correct or not?

Comment: You mean *year of construction*.

Comment: Ok,i know i can use that too...but i would really like when someone could explain me if "Year of built " is correct or not,and why.

Comment: *Year of build*, not built. ( built is a verb, not a noun) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=year+of+construction%2Cyear+of+build+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyear%20of%20construction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyear%20of%20build%3B%2Cc0. The more common expression is "Year of construction".

Comment: Agreed, @Josh61.  'Build' can be used as a noun, as in 'It's a new build'.

Comment: No ! ! ! ! ! ! !

Comment: 'Year of built' is wrong grammatically ('built' is a past participle/verb not a noun). 'Year of build' is ostensibly correct with appropriate context ('build' can be used as a noun, but it is a newer usage) but is just not used. You can say 'year of construction' (and that sounds perfectly OK in a sentence). But do you want to place a marker on a building? Then you'd say 'Built 1922' or just '1922' and people know that it was the year of construction (or when construction ended).

Answer (score 4):

> Year of built 1922

No, that is incorrect because you cannot use 'of' before a verb (other than a gerund).

**Possibilities**

Year of build, 1922

Year of construction, 1922

Year built, 1922

Comment: "Year of build" is not really idiomatic, either; sure, I've seen "date of build" for software, but that's a very specific usage of "build" that would not apply to a building except, perhaps, in the construction industry itself.

Comment: 'year of build' is the usual term in shipping. --- https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bmcgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22year+of+build%22&dq=%22year+of+build%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwB2oVChMI35e6sOnLxwIVIoHbCh3pUwYC ---  I'll see if I can find examples for land-based structures.

Comment: But, again, that's an industry usage and not a general usage, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Well we don't know that gigounon isn't in the building industry!  Actually I have searched and only found a couple of references to 'year of build' that apply to housing. This is compared with hundreds that refer to shipping. I think I have to agree with you.